Нужно ли тире в предложении с «одно и то же»?
Каждый раз по прибытии — одно и то же.
Каждый раз по прибытии одно и то же.

• О предложениях такого типа (неполных) и о пунктуации в них очень хорошо сказано в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина (Тире в неполном предложении):

§ 18. В самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым, не восстанавливаемым из контекста, может ставиться тире. Такие предложения расчленены паузой на два компонента — обстоятельственный и подлежащный: За решеткой — сказочная птица (Забол.); В переулках на селе — грязь по колено (Шукш.); Над желтыми соломенными полями, над стерней — синее небо да белые облака (Сол.)...
Однако при отсутствии паузы и логического ударения на обстоятельственном члене предложения тире не ставится: Там на неведомых дорожках следы невиданных зверей (П.).

• Примеры (с разным оформлением)
— Что тут расследовать? Родственники твои по пьяни подожгли. Каждое лето — одно и то же... (А. Григорян. Комарова).
— Когда кончится весь этот бардак? — спросил Николаич у шкафа с документацией. — Каждый год одно и то же (Д. Карапузов. Витька).
✦ В вашем предложении два обстоятельства подряд (каждый раз [когда?] по прибытии [когда?]). После них мне очень хочется сделать паузу и, соответственно, поставить тире:
Каждый раз по прибытии — одно и то же.
Окончательное же решение (ставить тире или нет?) принимает автор предложения — в зависимости от контекста.

ДОПОЛНЮ ответ рассказом о том, как автор выбирает тире.
Вариант 1. Перечисляем проблемы на вокзале, потом делаем вывод:
Каждый раз по прибЫтии // — одно и тО же.
Тема закончена, два ударения, пауза, тире.
Вариант 2. Каждый раз по прибытии одно и тО же. Далее перечисляем проблемы.
Тема только начата, одно ударение, нет паузы.
Это эллиптическое предложение, построенное по схеме: обстоятельство — подлежащее. Тире интонационное, определяется по расстановке ударений и наличию паузы. При постановке тире ударением выделена ПЕРВАЯ ЧАСТЬ, делается пауза.  Но если ударение уходит В КОНЕЦ предложения, то паузы и тире нет.
Поэтому и особых тайн нет, это простой интонационный анализ. Интуитивно мы читаем текст правильно, поэтому нам  "хочется или не хочется" поставить тире. Постановка знаков по слуху — это отнюдь не утопия.
P. S.
Я бы назвала постанову ударения в первой части предложения ИНТОНАЦИОННЫМ ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕМ (термин Розенталя при выборе двоеточия).
В данной теме интонационный принцип особенно важен: во всех правилах говорится о наличии или отсутствии паузы, но об ударении упоминается также.
Розенталь

Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым): Влево, в углу, у дверей, на табурете — ведро воды для жаждущих (Пом.); При отсутствии паузы тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится: А в доме стук, ходьба… (Гр.); Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая (Л.);

ПАС
Примечание. Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи отражено произношение с логическим ударением на сказуемом: Моя сестра учительница (ср.: Моя сестра — учительница — ударение и на слове сестра, и на слове учительница).
